# How to search for wild card in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to search my User model for all Users that start with any integer, I have code for individual letters and it works, but Im having trouble getting it working with a wild card. Right now I have this code:

in my view:

```
<%= link_to '#', users_charlist_path(:char => '[0123456789]' %>
```

and in my controller I have:

```
def charlist
  @a = User.where('goal like ?', "#{params[:char]}%").to_a
end
```

how ever, '[0123456789]', doesnt seem to work as it does not return anythign to me even though I have users whose names begin with an integer. how do i do this?

Comment: check the logs to find the sql statement that active record is generating, that may give you a clue.  re-run that statement in the console of your database to see the results, this may give you insight.

Answer (score 0):

The `where` method is a part of `ActiveRecord` which maps the objects to the database. So how you can query the database with a regex depends on which db you are using not on ruby. You need to look up the regex functions of the database your using. For mysql you can find them here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/regexp.html

An alternative is to select all objects an use the `select` method to filter the results that match your needs. That method is documented here:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-select

On big amounts of data I whould suggest to use the database even if that means your application isnt 100% portable between different database systems.